# MERGE statement issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table `[ExistingTable]` with three columns: `ID`, `Value` and `Date`

```
+----+------------------+
| ID | Value | Date     |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | 100   |2016-01-01|
| 1  | 200   |2016-01-01|
| 1  | 300   |2016-01-01|
| 2  | 200   |2016-01-01|
| 2  | 300   |2016-01-01|
+----+------------------+
```

and the second table, `[NewTable]`

```
+----+------------+
| ID | Value      |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 100        |
| 1  | 200        |
| 1  | 400        |
| 2  | 200        |
| 2  | 300        |
+----+------------+
```

If i write a merge statement like:

```
MERGE [ExistingTable] AS T1
USING [NewTable] AS T2 ON (T1.[ID] = T2.[ID] AND T1.[Value] = T2.[Value])

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT([ID], [Value], [Date]) 
    VALUES(T2.[ID], T2.[Value], Getdate())

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET [Date] = Getdate();
```

The query will insert `ID = 1 AND Value = 400` and it will update dates for all the rest data.

**BUT**, I want to make `INSERT` for all the `ID` field values, which has not been matched, in this example, I want to get this kind of result:

```
+----+------------------+
| ID | Value | Date     |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | 100   |2016-01-01|
| 1  | 200   |2016-01-01|
| 1  | 300   |2016-01-01|
| 2  | 200   |2016-10-15|
| 2  | 300   |2016-10-15|
| 1  | 100   |2016-10-15|
| 1  | 200   |2016-10-15|
| 1  | 400   |2016-10-15|
+----+------------------+
```

Is it achievable with the **MERGE** statement?

Comment: your final output logic is not clear

Comment: *BUT, I want to make INSERT for all the ID field values, which has not been matched* ... but records `(1,100), (1,200)` *do* have a match.

Comment: If a `NOT MATCH` happens, I want to make insert all the data from `[NewTable]` which has **not matched** `[ID]` values, hope it makes sence..

Comment: But, records `(1,100), (1,200)` from `[NewTable]` **do** have a match. Why should they be inserted?

Comment: I know that they have a match and that's why I asked a question, if it is possible to write insert according to my logic. seems the answer is no..

Comment: I agree that the logic doesn't make sense... Perhaps if you explained the problem you are trying to solve we could help.

Comment: Just add the date field to your on clause so it checks the date too. Though this defeats merge and you could just use insert instead

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be done with CTE and INSERT:

```
;WITH cte AS ( --here we will store all ID's that have 1 and more not matched Values
SELECT n.ID
FROM [NewTable] n
LEFT JOIN ExistingTable e
    ON n.ID = e.id and n.[Value] = e.[Value]
WHERE e.ID IS NULL
)

INSERT INTO ExistingTable
SELECT  n.ID,
        n.[Value],
        GETDATE()
FROM [NewTable] n
INNER JOIN cte c
    ON c.ID = n.ID
```

If you then select from `ExistingTable` you will get:

```
ID  Value   Date
1   100     2016-01-01
1   200     2016-01-01
1   300     2016-01-01
2   200     2016-01-01
2   300     2016-01-01
1   100     2016-10-15
1   200     2016-10-15
1   400     2016-10-15
```

Comment: thanks @gofr1, but surely I needed it with `MERGE`. I already have the code with temp table and manual insert/update statements, I just wanted it with merge

Comment: Why merge? It is not a job of MERGE to insert data like you want, it is a job of INSERT.